# Make a backup of the whole server that can be restored later

Tags: linux, server, backup

I have a server with the following disk structure:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda3             219G  192G   17G  93% /

tmpfs                  16G     0   16G   0% /lib/init/rw

udev                   16G  124K   16G   1% /dev

tmpfs                  16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm

/dev/sda2             508M   38M  446M   8% /boot

/dev/sdb1             2.7T  130G  2.3T  5% /media/3TB1
```

I am interested in making  backup of the whole server on my local machine. When the time comes I want to be able to restore a new server from my local machine backup. What procedure do you recommend?

I tried `rsync`, but the indexing took extremely long so I aborted it. Than I used `scp`, and well, it is currently working. There is lots of symbolic links that weren't transferred to the local machine, and I worry I won't be able to restore it later on.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Since your sda isn't very large and a lot of it is used anyway, I'd create a complete backup of the block device.  Your sdb, however, is very large and used only to a small part.  Of that I'd create a file system backup.

1. Boot your server with a Ubuntu live CD and become root (`sudo su -`).
2. Attach your backup medium (I assume it's mounted as /mnt/backup/ in the following).
3. Create a block device backup of sda: `cat /dev/sda > /mnt/backup/sda`
4. Mount your sdb (I assume it's mounted as /media/3TB1/ in the following).
5. Create a file system backup of sdb: `rsync -av /media/3TB1/ /mnt/backup/sdb/`

For restoring the backup later:

1. Boot your server with a Ubuntu live CD and become root (`sudo su -`).
2. Attach your backup medium (I assume it's mounted as /mnt/backup/ in the following).
3. Restore the block device backup of sda: `cat /mnt/backup/sda > /dev/sda`
4. Mount your sdb (I assume it's mounted as /media/3TB1/ in the following).
5. Restore the file system backup of sdb: `rsync -av /mnt/backup/sdb/ /media/3TB1/`

There are more fancy ways of doing it for sure.  But this routine worked for me lots of times.

Comment: Downvotes (there is one) should be commented to help improve the answer.

Answer (score -1):

A backup of that size should take a long time to copy over the internet in any case: `rsync`, `cp` , `dd` ..etc, the time taken to copy the file depends on your internet speed.

In my opinion, `rsync` is the way to go, but if you're not willing to wait that long for the download to complete (I wouldn't either) I highly suggest backing your disk up on another remote server, unless you don't plan on restoring it later since uploading would be a pain too (especially on ADSL).

You have a few options:

- Ask your data center for disk redundancy.
- A cheap and highly unrecommended solution is to backup your most important data on a file sharing web service, eg. Dropbox (As far as I remember they had a shell API for many tasks including uploading files, which can be used for automatic backups).
- Wait for the download to finish.
- Go  with @Alfe's solution, which is pretty neat in my opinion.